# How to set out of office in Outlook so as to not reply when the incoming mail is addressed to a Group?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am a part of a mailing Group called "ITSupport".

If I set an out of office reply, it replies to all mails, including those addressed to the group.

How do I stop this?

I am using Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating or editing the rule, under "Which condition(s) do you want to check?", select the "sent only to me", or the "when my name is in the To box" check box.